# In python how do I assign a series of commands to one variable?

Tags: python, dictionary, function

I'm self teaching myself python by delving right in. I'm not sure if a function does this if you leave it empty:

```
#My first section that pulls a value from a random shuffle of codes
print "\n"
print "-"*10
print 'This is a test of the %s system'% codes[0]
print "-"*10
print "\n"

#My second section that pulls a value from a random shuffle of codes
print "\n"
print "-"*10
print 'This is not a test of the %s system and all is good'% codes[1]
print "-"*10
print "\n"
```

My question is, is there a way to make it nicer looking and with fewer lines of code? Or am I stuck with having 10 lines of print?

Comment: Everyone had such great answers. I tried all of them and they work great. I picked the one that worked best for my purposes. Thanks so much everyone for your awesome input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show different messages, you can define a function that receives the message to be printed:

```
def print_message(message):
    print "\n"
    print "-"*10
    print message
    print "-"*10
    print "\n"

print_message('This is a test of the %s system' % codes[0])
print_message('This is not a test of the %s system and all is good'% codes[1])
```

Comment: This works great. How would I create an if statement based on the results of the print_message? I keep getting an error when I try and I think it's because the result is randomized or that I can't create a variable to run against an if statement based on the def.

Example: If the first print_message == "A", print the print_message from above AND print another message right below it saying "I see that the result is A. That is great"

Comment: You have to return whatever you want in the function. Add a return statement in print_message and then you can check what's returned using if print_message('My message') == 'A'. You can also assign the result to a variable like my_result = print_message('My message'). if my_result == 'A' ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function:

```
def print_stuff(what,addendum=''):
    print "\n"
    print "-"*10
    print 'This is a test of the %s system%s' % (what,addendum)
    print "-"*10
    print "\n"

print_stuff(codes[0])
print_stuff(codes[1],addendum = " and all is good")
```

Comment: This works great too. How could I use addendum with the result of the first print_stuff(codes[0]) to print a message IF the result is a specific string.

Answer (score 3):

Python has quite awesome multiline strings:

```
def print_it(somethig):
    print """
----------
This is a test of the {} system.
----------
""".format(something)

print_it(0)
print_it(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function with the index number:

```
def print_codes(i):
    #My first section that pulls a value from a random shuffle of codes
    print "\n"
    print "-"*10
    print 'This is a test of the %s system'% codes[i]
    print "-"*10
    print "\n"

print_codes(0)
print_codes(1)
```

Also read this [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)